# I keep receiving an error that "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when running my code

Tags: python, json, url

I am working on an assignment where I have written a program that retrieves data from the URL:
[http://derekowens.com/cs/satellites.aspx?p={planet}](http://derekowens.com/cs/satellites.aspx?p=%7Bplanet%7D)
Where in place of {planet}, I can put one of the planets in our solar system, such as Earth, Jupiter, etc. This URL then gives me data about the moons of the inputted planet. My program retrieves this data, loads the data from the JSON string into a Python variable, and then examines the orbit_radius data to determine which moon is the closest to the planet. My code is the following:

```
import urllib.request
import json

planets = ["Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"]
for planet in planets:
    url = f"http://derekowens.com/cs/satellites.aspx?p={planet}"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    print(data)
    moons = data["satellites"]

    
    closest_moon = min(moons, key=lambda x: x["orbit_radius"])["moon"]
    print(f"{planet}, {closest_moon}, {min(moons, key=lambda x: x['orbit_radius'])['orbit_radius']}")
```

But, after executing the code, I keep receiving the error:

```
moons = data["satellites"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I fix this so my code runs properly and displays six lines of output, one line of
information for each of the six planets, in this format:

Planet name, Moon name, Orbit radius

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the response from server you've got a list not a dictionary.

The correct code can look like this:

```py
import json
import urllib.request

planets = ["Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"]
for planet in planets:
    url = f"http://derekowens.com/cs/satellites.aspx?p={planet}"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())

    closest_moon = min(data, key=lambda x: x["orbit_radius"])
    print(f"{planet}, {closest_moon['name']}, {closest_moon['orbit_radius']}")
```

Prints:

```
Mars, Phobos, 9380
Jupiter, Metis, 128000
Saturn, S/2009 S 1, 117000
Uranus, Cordelia, 49800
Neptune, Naiad, 48224
Pluto, Charon, 19591
```